# Convert address field to coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a field called **ADDRESS** on my webpage. I also have a field called **COORDINATES** on my webpage. Can someone give me specific JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT code to take the address in **ADDRESS** and have lattitude and longitude coordinates show up in **COORDINATES** field.

**EXAMPLE**

ADDRESS - 1 MetLife Stadium Dr, East Rutherford, NJ 07073

COORDINATES - 40.814209   /   -74.073690

Please give a specific example. I know i might need an API key or something. I tried looking at google maps API documentation, but it was a bit confusing. Thank You.

Comment: This is called reverse geocoding and the google maps geocode API has all the information you need to do this. Finding examples is not hard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = jQuery('#address').val();

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    jQuery('#coordinates').val(latitude+', '+longitude);
    } 
}); 
</script>
```